# VBA code to get a data from meta XML to doc

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n49Qm.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycgk5.png)

Need code in VBA, I've been attempting for a month to obtain data from meta XML to doc. For example, I need to get the para in the tag caption provided in XML and put it at the conclusion of the active doc.

Comment: There are plenty of questions just here on SO which cover how to read XML using VBA.  If you've tried for a month, you must already have found some of those posts and tried some code, so consider editing your question to show the code you tried, and explain exactly what problem(s) you're facing.  That's the best way to get help here.